# Unable to run the script in nest js getting missing script error

Tags: reactjs, typescript, docker, nestjs

I have added the script in my packege.json file,but when trying to run in terminal by using command " npm run seed:ambassadors " it gives error missing script ,[image]

Error:

```
    npm ERR! missing script: seed:ambassadors

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2022-12-29T11_33_08_599Z-debug.log
```

docker-compose.yaml
[image]

packege.json

```
"scripts": {
    "prebuild": "rimraf dist",
    "build": "nest build",
    "format": "prettier --write \"src/**/*.ts\" \"test/**/*.ts\"",
    "start": "nest start",
    "start:dev": "nest start --watch",
    "start:debug": "nest start --debug --watch",
    "start:prod": "node dist/main",
    "lint": "eslint \"{src,apps,libs,test}/**/*.ts\" --fix",
    "test": "jest",
    "test:watch": "jest --watch",
    "test:cov": "jest --coverage",
    "test:debug": "node --inspect-brk -r tsconfig-paths/register -r ts-node/register node_modules/.bin/jest --runInBand",
    "test:e2e": "jest --config ./test/jest-e2e.json",
    "seed:ambassadors": "ts-node src/command/ambassador.seeder.ts"
  },
```

NOTE: I am running that "npm run seed:ambassadors" commad in docker container and to run docker container I am using "docker-compose exec backend sh".

any suggestion plzzzz?????

Comment: You've added the `docker` tag, but you have given no information about how you run it in docker. But one thing to ask is: "have you rebuilt your image?"

Comment: yes,Actually I am running that "npm run seed:ambassadors" commad in docker container.

Comment: and to run docker container I am using "docker-compose exec backend sh"

Comment: `exec` doesn't start a new container. You need to `stop` the container and `run` a new one for it to have the changes in the new image.

Comment: Yes,But I want to run "npm run seed:ambassadors" command in docker backend

Comment: what we can tell is that the working dir that you ran `npm run` isn't the one that has the `package.json`. Or the `package.json` file in there does not have the `seed:ambassadors` npm-script.

Comment: ambasssador.seeder.ts file is present inside the src/command/ambasssador.seeder.ts,so that seed:ambassadors is my custom script which I want to run iside docker container shell so first to open shell I am using command: docker-compose exec backend sh ,then I run the "npm run seed:ambassadors" command inside the docker shell...

Comment: @ Micael Levi I have added screenshots of docker-compose.yaml and update the error screenshot with exact file....